# Dynamically change Status in Document Approval process

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, content-approval

I am working on document approval process in SharePoint Online document library where I have enabled "Require content approval for submitted items? to Yes". I want to develop a Power Automate flow to handle this approval process. I was referring [this article](https://tomriha.com/how-to-set-content-approval-status-with-power-automate/) where it is mentioned that any documents we create or upload goes through this status **Draft** ->**Pending** ->**Approved**, but what I see is once I create a document, it is automatically going to "**Pending**" state, which I don't need. I need first document should be in "**Draft**" mode, then once user submit for approval, the status will be changed to "**Pending**". I was thinking I can add a flag column in SPO list for the approval flow, once user select this flag checkbox column, then only the approval flow will be triggered. But here the problem is, automatically the document approval status is set to "Pending" once user creates a document. How to control this one - like it has to go in this sequence Draft -> Pending -> Approved